# Cant Access a "error" folder in subdomain.localhost/error/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to put all of my error documents into one folder in my website root.

Ideally I would like all of my error documents to go into `http://subdomain.localhost/error/` but whenever I load the URL in my browser I get a message **`Access forbidden!`** `Error 403`.

I then removed the `.htaccess` file from the document root. The content of the `.htaccess` file is:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /err_docs/401
ErrorDocument 401 /err_docs/401
ErrorDocument 404 /err_docs/404
ErrorDocument 500 /err_docs/500

IndexIgnore * # prevent directory listing

Order deny,allow
Allow from *
```

`/err_docs/` is my current folder for my error documents - (Because `/error` doesn't work).

Upon inspecting the apache error log I find:
`[Thu Jun 25 13:46:57.445385 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 5104:tid 1760] [client 127.0.0.1:51853] AH01276: Cannot serve directory C:/xampp/apache/error/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.pl,index.cgi,index.asp,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,default.php,default.pl,default.cgi,default.asp,default.shtml,default.html,default.htm,home.php,home.pl,home.cgi,home.asp,home.shtml,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

I have tried the following:

- Removed `.htaccess` from the document root. (From both the sub domain and the domain).
- Checked that there isn't another `.htaccess` file in apache's folders

I am happy to go finding the result on google but I have no idea what to search. Can any body tell me where to start looking for the issue, or what to look for?

**Update**
This is the contents of my virtual hosts config file:

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "C:\web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "C:\web"
</VirtualHost>

#######################################

NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory 'C:\\Personal\\Web'>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ServerName personal.localhost
ServerAlias personal.localhost
DocumentRoot 'C:\\Personal\\Web'
</VirtualHost>

#######################################
```

Comment: Using a folder named `error` works fine for me with the above `.htaccess` file. Have you really placed the corresponding error documents inside the folder e.g 401, 404 and 500?

Comment: @Cyclone I don't think the problem is with the `.htaccess` file, because if I remove the file from the directory I am still not able to access the folder.
I sure the problem is elsewhere, but I am not sure where, but I've been a member of this community for long enough to know that someone will ask to see the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: What permissions have you set on the folder serving your error documents?

Comment: @Cyclone full permissions, I have not denied any other permissions, as I do all my validation in my sites code files (To prevent unwanted access). I am also the administration on this machine and I do not have UAC enabled (Windows 7 and XAMPP)

Comment: Try to restart your server, maybe it hasn't picked up the updates to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Cyclone I have just restarted my Apache Server (Aswell as my computer) but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the virtual host config?

Comment: Ive updated my post to contain the config files contents

Comment: What have you set as `DocumentRoot` in your httpd.conf? Shouldn't all your DocumentRoots be located under `C:/xampp/htdocs` or similar?

Comment: Not Necessarily, that defeats the point of being able to have sub domains. Also if your sub domain is in your `DocumentRoot` then if your website gets compromised so do your sub domains, and vice versa. My Document Root is `C:\Web`

Comment: delete cache from your browser, or close and open it again

Comment: Ive tried deleting cache, and multiple browsers / computers, problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly same problem today. While googling I came to this question. Since the question was unanswered and none of the comments helped me, I asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914396) with my observation that /error was being served from **ServerRoot** instead of **DocumentRoot**. In the comments I got a suggestion to check for an alias for /error. Finally I got the alias in the file **xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf**. Commenting the `Alias` directive makes **error** folder in document root accessible. Please note that commenting the alias may have side-effects as there are many uses of /error folder-files in other configuration files mostly to define `ErrorDocument`.