# /error Directory is not accessible

Tags: apache

In my document root I have created a directory named error and some files inside it. Whenever I try to access localhost/error, I get 403 forbidden error. There is an unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049703) about the exact same problem. The error log for the error is as following

> [Sun Aug 19 09:00:52.317995 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 3536:tid 1592] [client ::1:61437] AH01276: Cannot serve directory **F:/xampp/apache/error/**: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.pl,index.cgi,index.asp,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,default.php,default.pl,default.cgi,default.asp,default.shtml,default.html,default.htm,home.php,home.pl,home.cgi,home.asp,home.shtml,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

After seeing the log I came to know that the **/error** directory is appended to **ServerRoot (F:/xampp/apache)** instead of **DocumentRoot (F:/xampp/htdocs)**. Apache is doing the above only for /error. It is working as expexted for other directories.  Can someone tell me the reason and source of this problem?

Comment: check Apache configuration files, is there an alias defined for /error ?

Comment: Well I got the source of problem after digging two hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission on the directory using chmod -R 777. I was facing the same issue and this worked for me